# FB Login button in HTML 5 with JS redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-login

In the older version of the FB Login button, this worked well for me

```
<fb:login-button scope='email,publish_stream'>Login</fb:login-button>
<div id='fb-root'></div>

 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>     
 <script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID(); ?>',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
   });
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
   });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
  });
   };
  (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script'); 
      e.async = true;e.src =   document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());
  </script>
```

But, a friend of mine recently suggested switching to the new HTML 5 Login button as follows:

```
  <div id='fb-root'></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APPID';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
```

This works well too. Except that I can't find a way for JS to trigger a redirect to /fb_redirect.php. In the older example,

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
   });
```

worked just fine. But, I need for the user to be redirected to /fb_redirect.php so that PHP can start a session and insert some of the user's FB info into the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a signature careless error of mine. The answer was in the first part of this question.

It simply was to add

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
```

});

Answer (score 1):

here is your default parameter

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : <?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>,
  status     : false,
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true
 });
};

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Here is my custom fb_login function, my custom function fb_login () fetches the uid and accessToken values and does the rest of the operation. This time it happens only when login button is clicked.

```
function fb_login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID; 
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                if ((parseFloat(uid) == parseInt(uid)) && !isNaN(uid)) {
                  window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';

                  }
     }
        });
      }

</script>
```

I have extended the FB login button with onlogin event which calls a JS function fb_login() when user click on login with facebook button and successfully loggedin.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="fb_login()"></div>
```